# PHP - Why flush (and or ob_flush) is not working?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, sleep, flush

Self explanatory BUT not working...

Just want to echo $j every 1 second...

```
ob_implicit_flush();
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();

for ($j=0;$j<=9;$j++){
    echo $j.'<br>';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Get rid of the `@`. That hides errors. How do you expect to know what's wrong if you hide errors from yourself?

Comment: No error(s) @John :) with or without the @...

Comment: Clear the browser's cache

Comment: PHP output can get cached in many other places: Apache, proxy, browser... Don't assume the problem is necessarily in your PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's buffer is just one of many.

The server may be buffering output, and some browsers buffer input so it's not trying to re-render the entire page for every byte that's received.

As a general rule, you should *never* use `sleep` in anything that the browser will call, because that's just asking to be DoS attacked, really...

So basically this answer is to tell you "don't do that". There is certainly a better way to do what you're doing, starting as simple as JavaScript:

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var count = 0, box = document.getElementById('counter');
        function step() {
            box.appendChild(document.createTextNode(count));
            box.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            count++;
            if( count <= 9) setTimeout(step,1);
        }
        step();
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I'd say "never use `sleep`, period".  :P  But that's a discussion topic for another time.

Comment: @cHao When you're building console apps in PHP, `sleep` is very useful. I made a text-based Connect 4 game and used `usleep` to program the animation of the played piece falling into place, which was awesome XD So not "never", just "exceptionally rarely and only if you genuinely need it" :p

Comment: Who said he's using a browser and not the cli?

Comment: @Rob OP did. `echo '<br>';`.